# How is the operation in the $n$-th group in the singular cochain complex defined exactly?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know that the $n$-th group in the singular cochain complex is $C^n:=\operatorname{Hom}(C_n,\mathbb{Z})$, but what is the operation between two elements in $C^n$?

I tried addition, and it makes no sense.

Comment: It's pointwise addition. What doesn't make sense about it?

Comment: $(\alpha+\beta)(x)=\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$

Comment: I know see where my mistake was. Thanks!